# Astronomical waste (Wasting All the Energy of the Universe no using it) and moral views against this, what are those?

Tags: ethics

I was reading a paper by Nick Bostrom [this one to be exact](https://nickbostrom.com/astronomical/waste) and I am lost in what moral views there are that share the opposition to astronomical waste that he associates with Utilitarism.

Most concretely he says

> " Utilitarians are not the only ones who should strongly oppose astronomical waste. There are many views about what has value that would concur with the assessment that the current rate of wastage constitutes an enormous loss of potential value. For example, we can take a thicker conception of human welfare than commonly supposed by utilitarians (whether of a hedonistic, experientialist, or desire-satisfactionist bent), such as a conception that locates value also in human flourishing, meaningful relationships, noble character, individual expression, aesthetic appreciation, and so forth. So long as the evaluation function is aggregative (does not count one person’s welfare for less just because there are many other persons in existence who also enjoy happy lives) and is not relativized to a particular point in time (no time-discounting), the conclusion will hold."

What are these moral views that Nick Bostrom refers to. Is there at least a significant list of examples?

Comment: I think protestant ethics is anti waste. Can't quite recall

Comment: "John Calvin and his adherents taught that any form of waste must be frowned at,"

Comment: Also might be a ref. to nonutilitarian environmental ethics broadly, like ecocentrism (land/territory having intrinsic value).

Comment: Which conclusion is he talking about in the last line?

Comment: Apparently "astronomical waste" refers to the idea we are currently wasting the energy of the sun by not having a Dyson sphere around it. I think the question would attract more quality answers if you made it clear in the question's body, because this is a very, very niche concern. My first idea was that it's about the resources wasted in vanity space programs, others might get it wrong too.

Comment: @armand Do you know if Utilitarism was already refuted?

Comment: Utilitarianism is a moral theory trying to codify "what people should do" type of questions. As such it can't really be refuted (the infamous is/ought problem). But it can be critiqued, and has been extensively (how exactly are we supposed to measure and compare utility, or if it even makes sense, being a key point of debate)

Comment: Even from an utilitarian perspective, Bostrom argument is dubious. He seems to take for granted that Dyson spheres can be done. I for one think it's a pipe dream, and my opinion is at least as good as anyone when it come to Kardashev type II civilization projects like Dyson spheres. If we consider Dyson spheres to be a pipe dream, investing resource toward their realization becomes in itself a waste.

Comment: @armand although Dyson spheres are dubious, it cannot said the same to the so-called Dyson swarms, they are very realistic.

Comment: @armand Proving that Interpersonal Utility cannot be compared, would no count as refuting Utilitarism?

Comment: @ErdelvonMises i wouldn't consider sending and maintaining billions of billions of satellites around the sun to the point they catch a significant part of its energy output "very realistic", but that's out of the scope of this site. The idea that utility can't be compared has been around for a while, yet there still are utilitarians who have issued answers to this critique, like the idea that having an heuristic, albeit imperfect, is always better than chaos or blindly following tradition or revelation. It's not a refutation per se, as utilitarianism does not assert any facts.

Comment: In the provided passage, it specifically says *"views about what has value"* and then goes on to list possible values -- *"human flourishing, meaningful relationships, noble character, individual expression, aesthetic appreciation".* Hence, the answer appears right there. After all, values essentially *are* views. Naturally, for one of these values to apply here, one would need to place value in maximising *hypothetical* expression of the value, rather than simply manifesting or protecting it within existing subjects. This assumes further that additional units have net positive goodness.